# Inline conditional statement clarification

Tags: php, syntax

I am sorry for the vague question title. I'm not sure what the actual name of this shorthand method is. If someone wants to help clarify how I should refer to this, I'll be glad to change the question title.

In the following code snippet:

`$account = $value->uid ? user_load($value->uid) : '';`

I am a little confused on what this code does. Here is what I think it does:
`if $value->uid exists
 then $account = user_load($value->uid) 
else 
$account = ''`

Is that correct?

Comment: [documentation can be found here](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php#language.operators.comparison.ternary)

Comment: Most answers are correct but there is one important point to consider: readability. Ternary operators are "bad" to read. Maintainability of code is one important aspect and easy to read and readable code makes it easier to maintain the code. A recommended book on that topic http://www.amazon.com/Clean-Code-Handbook-Software-Craftsmanship/dp/0132350882

Comment: @burzum - yeah, readability was very much an issue here - it just wasn't immediately clear what was happening here. I understand it now though, thanks to the excellent answers given.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is known as a [ternary operator](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/%3F%3a).

It means, if `$value->uid` is **truthy**, then `$account = user_load($value->uid)`. Otherwise, `$account = ''`.

These values are considered "falsy" in PHP:

- null
- 0
- 0.0
- "0"
- ""
- false
- array()

Comment: so if $value->uid returns say the number 322, that would be considered truthy, yes?

Comment: Yes. Take a look at [this article](http://www.phabricator.com/docs/phabricator/article/PHP_Pitfalls.html) for a more thorough explanation on truthy and falsey values.

Answer (score 3):

It's the same as:

```
if ($value->uid) {
    $account = user_load($value->uid);
} else {
    $account = '';
}
```

Answer (score 3):

They're called ternary statements. And yes, you're almost correct. *Almost*.

> if `$value->uid` exists then `$account = user_load($value->uid)` else `$account = ''`

This would be more correct:

> If the output of `$value->uid` is `TRUE`, then `$account = user_load($value->uid)`, else, `$account = ''`

---

Using normal `if/else` blocks, it'd be:

```
if( $value->uid ) {
    $account = user_load($value->uid);
} else {
    $account = '';
}
```

The documentation can be found [here](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php).

Answer (score 1):

It is called the ternary operator.

See this link: http://davidwalsh.name/php-shorthand-if-else-ternary-operators

Answer (score 1):

It's the PHP [ternary operator](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php), which works pretty much exactly like the ternary in other languages:

```
$value = ($test_value) ? 'true result' : 'false result';
```

is fully equivalent to

```
if ($test_value) {
    $value = 'true result';
} else {
    $value = 'false result';
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Your assumption is partialy correct.

```
$account = $value->uid ? user_load($value->uid) : '';
```

is the same as

```
if ($value->uid) {
  $account = user_load($value->uid);
} else  {
  $account = '';
}
```

the `if ($value->uid)` does not just check if the variable exists. It will return false if the variable is `undefined`, `null`, `false`, `0` or `''` (and I am probably forgetting some here)